# Switch case in java with condition on selection of cases

Tags: java

The following code consists of a switch case which executes five times asking the customer for the five icecream options ,but the condition is that each time the customer must select a different icecream if he selects the same icecream again it should display an error could someone help me with the above logic please ,or suggest me a better method than switch case.

```
class Icecreams {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        for( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Select an Icecream:\n1.Strawberry\n2.Vanilla\n3.Chocolate\n4.Butterscotch\n5.Black current\n6.Exit");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

            switch( n ) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("STRAWBERRY-Rs.50");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("VANILLA-Rs.40");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("CHOCOLATE-Rs.60");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("BUTTERSCOTCH-Rs.70");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("BLACKCURRENT-Rs.40");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Exit");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Select from the available choice");
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the previous choice of ice-cream in a variable and check?

Comment: What should happen if the user chooses Strawberry, Vanilla, Strawberry? Should the third choice be accepted or rejected?

Comment: The Third choice must be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend this code to your problem.This solution is easy-looking and short.You should easily understand where to change.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0, selection;
        ArrayList<Integer> selectionsSoFar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (n < 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter Option:\n");
            selection = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (selectionsSoFar.contains(selection) || selection <= 0 || selection > 2) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            } else {
                switch (selection) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1");
                    selectionsSoFar.add(selection);
                    n++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("2");
                    selectionsSoFar.add(selection);
                    n++;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        keyboard = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Really worked well Thank you.can i display the selections made using the from the array list

Comment: yes you can iterate through ArrayList like code this:

for( Integer i : selectionsSoFar)
  {
   System.out.println(i);
  }

Answer (score 2):

You could do this: Put the possible ice creams in a `List`, i.e. an `ArrayList`, and every time an ice cream is chosen, you remove the corresponding ice cream from that `ArrayList`.

You could also use the very same `ArrayList` for displaying the menu of choices to the user.

The advantage of using the `ArrayList` is that you will not have to modify your program if the selection of ice creams changes in future. As a rule of thumb: *Put abstractions in code, detail in data.* (Dave Thomas, Andrew Hunt http://pragmatictips.com/38)

You could then, later on, even modify the program to read the ice creams from a file, so you only have to change a text file when the selection of ice creams changes.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, you need to save the previous choice. So it may look something like this:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        int previousChoice = 0;
        for( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Select an Icecream:\n1.Strawberry\n2.Vanilla\n3.Chocolate\n4.Butterscotch\n5.Black current\n6.Exit");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            while (previousChoice == n) {
                System.out.println("Can't select the same ice-cream twice in a row, try again.");
                n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            }
            previousChoice = n; // save previous choice

            switch( n ) {
```

Disclaimer: this only works if you need to avoid selecting the same ice-cream twice in a row. If you need to make sure the choice is always *unique*, the solution will be different, but it'd be good to clarify it in your question.

Comment: `while (previousChoice == n)` That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: "Repeat entry until the choice is different". Yes, this checks for the previous choice only - hence the error "can't select the same ice-cream twice in a row". This is how I understood the OP's question anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String I = "Icecream Rs. 10.";
        String S = "Sandwitch Rs.5";
        String C = "Cake Rs.15";
        String Ch = "Chocolate Rs.5";
        String L = "Lemon water Rs.12";
        int limit = 6;

        System.out.println(
                "Select your choice from below options of 1 - 5 \n" + 
        "1 :" + I + "\n2 :" + S + "\n3 :" + C + "\n4 :" + Ch + "\n5 :" + L);
        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("You have chosen a item " + I);
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("You have chosen a item " + S);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("You have chosen a item " + C);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("You have chosen a item " + Ch);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("You have chosen a item " + L);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Select only from the available choice of 1 - 5");
                break;

            }

        }

    }
}
```